# How to show helperText in red color using material-ui in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My objective is to show helperText in red color as we show in error time. But i couldn't make it.
Couldn't able to figure it out where i'm going wrong.

Here is the code:

```
class Sample extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      channel: -1,
      sports: -1,
      movie: ""
    };
  }
  handleChange = (e: any) => {
    this.setState({ channel: e.target.value });
  };
  handleSports = (e: any) => {
    this.setState({ sports: e.target.value });
  };

  handleMovie = (e: any) => {
    this.setState({ movie: e.target.value });
  };

  Valid = () => {
    const errors = { channel: "", sports: "", movie: "" };
    if (!this.state.channel) {
      errors.channel = "Please select channel";
    }
    if (!this.state.sports) {
      errors.sports = "select Sports";
    }
    if (!this.state.movie) {
      errors.movie = "select movie";
    }
    return {
      errors,
      isSubmit: Object.keys(errors).length === 0
    };
  };

  handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
      channel: this.state.channel,
      sports: this.state.sports,
      movie: this.state.movie
    };
    console.log(data);
  };

  render() {
    const { errors, isSubmit } = this.Valid();
    return (
      <>
        <FormControl>
          <Select
            defaultValue={-1}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            displayEmpty
            inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Without label" }}
          >
            <MenuItem value={-1}>Select Channel</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={10}>Sports</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={20}>Entertainment</MenuItem>
          </Select>
          {!this.state.channel ? (
            <FormHelperText>{errors.channel}</FormHelperText>
          ) : null}
        </FormControl>
        {this.state.channel === 10 ? (
          <div>
            <FormControl>
              <Select
                defaultValue={-1}
                onChange={this.handleSports}
                displayEmpty
                inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Without label" }}
              >
                <MenuItem value={-1}>Select </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={10}>Star sports 1</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={20}>Star sports 2</MenuItem>
              </Select>
              {!this.state.sports ? (
                <FormHelperText>{errors.sports}</FormHelperText>
              ) : null}
            </FormControl>
          </div>
        ) : this.state.channel === 20 ? (
          <div>
            <FormControl>
              <Select
                defaultValue={-1}
                onChange={this.handleMovie}
                displayEmpty
                inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Without label" }}
              >
                <MenuItem value={-1}>Select</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={10}>Star Movies</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={20}>ABC</MenuItem>
              </Select>
              {!this.state.movie ? (
                <FormHelperText>{errors.movie}</FormHelperText>
              ) : null}
            </FormControl>
          </div>
        ) : null}
        <div>
          <Button disabled={isSubmit} onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
            Submit
          </Button>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default Sample;
```

[Here is the working sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-surf-93364)

I don't know why it is not appearing in red color. Struggling a lot with this issue.
Can anyone please help me in this query?

Comment: You want the text "Select Movie" to be in Red?

Comment: @edison16029 - Hi, Yes , I have kept helpertext for 3 dropdowns, if they wont select any dropdown value then i want to display the helperText should show in red color. Could you please help me with that

Comment: Did you try adding style={{color : "red"}} to the <FormHelperText>. Like <FormHelperText style={{color : "red"}}>{errors.channel}</FormHelperText>

Comment: It worked in the sandbox, let me know if it works

Answer (score 8):

pass error prop like this:

```
    <FormControl error={!this.state.channel}>
      <Select
        defaultValue={-1}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        displayEmpty
        inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Without label" }}
      >
        <MenuItem value={-1}>Select Channel</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={10}>Sports</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={20}>Entertainment</MenuItem>
      </Select>
      {!this.state.channel ? (
        <FormHelperText>{errors.channel}</FormHelperText>
      ) : null}
    </FormControl>
```

or just like this

```
    <FormHelperText error>{errors.channel}</FormHelperText>
```

here is the document: https://material-ui.com/api/form-helper-text/